# Keras + Tensorflow model convert to coreml exits NameError: global name ... is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, keras, coreml, coremltools

I've adapted the VAE example from the keras site to train on my data, and everything runs fine. But I'm unable to convert to coreml. The error is:

```
NameError: global name `batch_size' is not defined
```

Since batch_size clearly is defined in the python source, I'm guessing it has to do with how the conversion tool captures variable names. Does anyone know how I can fix it (or whether it is, indeed, possible to fix)?

Many thanks,

J.

Comment: So, I got further by removing the variable declarations from the python code and copying the values directly into the keras/tensorflow functions. However, after that it fails on ValueError:  `Unknown layer: CustomVariationalLayer`
But at least that makes sense—coremltools isn't happy with custom layers. 
If anybody has adapted the keras VAE example (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py) to remove the custom layer, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems this CustomVariationalLayer only defines a loss function, and loss functions are used during training only. (I haven't worked with VAEs yet so maybe they use loss for other things too?) In any case, I'd try saving the model without this layer.

Comment: Ah, right... Good point. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar message when using parameters to construct the neural net. This should work:

```
from keras import models

batch_size = 50    

model = models.load_model(filename, custom_objects={'batch_size': batch_size})
```

See also documentation: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model